# Cannot login to Django admin with custom superuser

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication, django-auth-models

I am developing a custom `Author` user model for my blog site. The authors in this user model connect to my post application, another application of mine, with a foreign key and create the author-post relationship. However, I can't even log in to the Django admin panel, it says my password is wrong, but I'm sure it's correct. What is the reason of this?

> Please enter the correct email adresi and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.

My custom user model code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser,
    PermissionsMixin,
)


class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_superuser(self, email, firstName, lastName, password, **other_fields):

        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if other_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Buraya erişim izniniz bulunmamaktadır. Lütfen yöneticiyle iletişime geçiniz.")

        if other_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Buraya erişim sadece En üst düzey kullanıcılar içindir. Lütfen yöneticiyle iletişime Geçiniz")

        return self.create_user(email, firstName, lastName, password, **other_fields)

    def create_user(self, firstName, lastName, email, password, **other_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_("Email Adresinizi Doğrulamalısınız!"))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, firstName=firstName, lastName=lastName, **other_fields)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user


class Author(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(_("email adresi"), max_length=100, unique=True)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    displayName = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to="avatar")
    bgImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="background")
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False, unique=True)
    desc = models.TextField()
    jobName = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Author Job")
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["firstName", "lastName"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.displayName

    def get_slug(self):
        slug = slugify(self.title.replace("ı", "i"))
        unique = slug
        number = 1

        while Author.objects.filter(slug=unique).exists():
            unique = "{}-{}" .format(slug, number)
            number += 1

        return unique
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```py
> def create_superuser(self, email, firstName, lastName, password, **other_fields):
>
>     # ...
>
>     return self.create_user(email, firstName, lastName, password, **other_fields)
> ```

Fix the order of `create_user` parameters:

```py
# def create_user(self, firstName, lastName, email, password, **other_fields):
def create_user(self, email, firstName, lastName, password, **other_fields):
```